# Login with JMeter for performance testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, blazemeter

I'm using BlazeMeter recording tool and running it on JMeter, but in my response data I'm getting `CSRF token validation failed` when I try to test my web application's login page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible issue is, you are passing that token hard coded. you need to extract the new token every time comes in GET request and store into some variable and then have to pass that variable to POST request as @Dmitri T mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider a different structure of your test to make it behave like a real browser:

- Open Login Page ([HTTP Get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) Request)

  - Extract `_csrf_token` value from the response and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Perform Login ([HTTP Post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request). At this stage you need to provide credentials and **_csrf_token** from the previous request.

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Site](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more information with regards to bypassing [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) in JMeter tests.